# Interpolating for regular timed data using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, interpolation

I have 20 stations, in the table of which I have the coordinates and the value of the other 3 factors for 2020 with regular intervals of one day. Now I want to create a  raster for each of these 3 factors and for each day, which is the result of interpolation.

Is there a way to create this large number (365*3) of rasters faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something and come back when you get stuck. Something like this,
for each date create a feature layer, for each field interpolate:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

fc = r'C:\GIS\ArcMap_default_folder\Default.gdb\points123' #Point feature class, needs to be in a file geodatabase (for the where clause to work)
output_folder = r'C:\GIS\data\testdata' #Where the rasters will be saved

date_field = 'datefieldname' #field holding the dates (date type, not string)
value_fields = ['valuefield1','valuefield2','somefield3'] #field with the values to interpolate

all_dates = list({i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, date_field)}) #List all unique dates

for date in all_dates:
    #Create a feature layer of each unique date
    where = "{0}=date '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=fc, field=date_field), date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=fc, out_layer='lyr', where_clause=where)
    
    #For each field interpolate. This is untested since I dont have spatial analyst
    for fieldname in value_fields:
        outIDW = Idw(in_point_features='lyr', z_field=fieldname, cell_size=10)#, {power}, {search_radius}, {in_barrier_polyline_features})
        outIDW.save(os.path.join(output_folder, '{0}_{1}.tif'.format(fieldname, date.strftime('%Y%m%d')))
```